# Spring AOP after advice not working properly on getter function

Tags: spring, aop, getter, pointcut

In Spring Framework, I am facing a strange issue while working with AOP.
I have the following simple bean class for a greeting:

```
public class HelloBean {
    private String message;
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void displayGreeting() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**Below spring config:**

```
<beans>
    <bean id="hello" class="com.att.spring.main.HelloBean"/>

    <bean id="serviceCheck" class="com.att.spring.main.ServiceCheck" />

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="serviceCheck"> 
            <aop:pointcut id="greet"
                expression="execution(* *.getMessage(..))" />
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="greet"
                method="preRunMessage" />
            <aop:after pointcut-ref="greet"
                method="postRunMessage" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

**AOP Advice Methods:**

```
public class ServiceCheck {

    public void preRunMessage() {
        System.out.println("Runs before the greeting");
    }

    public void postRunMessage() {
        System.out.println("Runs after the greeting");
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring-beans.xml");
        HelloBean hello = (HelloBean) context.getBean("hello");
        hello.setMessage("Hello World");
        System.out.println(hello.getMessage());

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Runs before the greeting
Runs after the greeting
Hello World
```

**Question:**

Why are both advices (before and after) getting printed when I use getter as a pointcut. The advice work correctly when i use pointcut on displayGreeting() method??

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println()` is executed after the `hello.getMessage()`. You can check it with the debuger.

```
1)preRunMessage()
2)hello.getMessage()
3)postRunMessage()
4)the System.out.println() prints the string returned by hello.getMessage()
```

Try to print something in `hello.getMessage()`, it will be printed between pre and post RunMessage methods.